# Is containing Jenkins inside my user folder preventing me from accessing it via slave machine?

Tags: jenkins, automation, automated-tests, hudson

I installed jenkins as a war file to the location "C:\Users\loggeduser" in the .jenkins folder.

I'm trying to access a slave machine's node I set up using "Launch agent via java Web Start", but when it gets to the step where I must access the "http://IPaddress:8080/computer/Slavemachine/slave-agent.jnlp" in the slave, the page returns a 404, not found.

In the past, I had installed jenkins as windows service in the program files of the Master machine, and was able to access it the slave with no hassle.

This has me presuming that I can't access jenkins via the slave because it is currently under my logged in user folder, and thus can't be accessed by the slave.

Am I right to assume this? What method can I use to go about accessing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I had to edit the Firewall Inbound rules to allow port 8080 to be located on the slave machines